# Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential_4" (type Sequential)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

This is a simple code for creating,compile and fitting a model for a single layer

```
X = tf.cast(tf.constant(X),dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.cast(tf.constant(y),dtype=tf.float32)
```

#Set Random seed

```
tf.random.set_seed(42)
```

#1.create a model using the Sequential API

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
                             ])
```

#2.Compile the model

```
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mae,
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(),metrics=["mae"])
```

#Fit the model

```
model.fit(X,y,epochs = 5)
```

but I am getting this error at the end.

```
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 878, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 867, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 860, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 808, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 227, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" '

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential_6" (type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "dense_7" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (None,)
    
    Call arguments received:
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=float64)
      • training=True
      • mask=None
```

Why Sequential_6 and dense_7??? This is a single layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgetting the batch dimension. Your input to your model has to have the shape `(batch_size, features)`. Try something like this:

```
X = tf.cast(tf.constant([0.5]),dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.cast(tf.constant([0.6]),dtype=tf.float32)
X = tf.expand_dims(X, axis=0)
y = tf.expand_dims(y, axis=0)
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
                             ])
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mae,
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(),metrics=["mae"])

model.fit(X,y,epochs = 5)
```

`Sequential_6` is your model name, `dense_7` is the name of the `Dense` layer. Every time you run your model again, the numbers in the names are incremented.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have forgotten to mention the input_shape to the model.

Try this :

**Create a model using the Sequential API**

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])
```